# Can't get ajax request jquery, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

AoA,
   I dont why the function below is not working, or it works sometimes and sometimes fails! :(

```
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
             $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'GetNotSize' %}?user={{ username }}",
            success:function(data){
              alert(data);
            }
          });
});
    </script>
```

the above url in source view:  url: "/GetSize/?user=saad_lah",
it was working fine ... but when I restarted the server,
its shows nothing...there is no warning or error in browsers console. Can't figure out what's the error....

Comment: it could be a cross origin error. what browser?

Comment: You cannot make Ajax requests to external URLs, unless the server allows it. Google certainly doesn't. Without more context information I doubt we will be able to help you.

Comment: Try with your own page... don't do that with google. (by default, google domains block incoming connections, iframes an a big etc.)

Comment: okay....thanx, one problem solved, I changed the url to my origional one...the function was running fine unless I refreshed the page...it is not showing any thing again...why?

Answer (score 1):

Google won't let you access their server on this type of CORS (cross-origin) request.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/?_=1386263558835. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: okay....thanx, one problem solved, I changed the url to my origional one...the function was running fine unless I refreshed the page...it is not showing any thing again...why?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to monitor exactly what is going on . Console will show any JS errors, and Network tab should show all server responses. I recommend Chrome inspector.

Comment: thanks for the response! there is no error in browser's console...I just deleted the cache and restarted the server...but now the problem is same! :(

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/GetSize/?user=saad_lah
   when I goto the page above(the url from which I getting data) the data shown there is '0' (which I needed)...
and there is no GET request in console(debug console)

Comment: okay ... very thanks for your response....the error was "ajax.googleapis was unable to load correctly" :/